# Gauss's law and material dependency

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, dielectric

Is Gauss's law

> $$\Phi_E = \oint \vec{E}\cdot{d}\vec{a}=\frac{Q_{int}}{\epsilon_0}$$

dependent on material properties? If yes, how should it change based on the material involved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think instead $\vec{s}$ there should be $d\vec{a}$

Comment: @Knight seems like I forgot a d, thanks!

Comment: Into the denominator there is in the vacuum $\epsilon_0$ and not $e_0$ (fix typo). When there is dependence of the material (without the vacuum) there is $\epsilon=\epsilon_r \epsilon_0$.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastiano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The equation you have written is absolute, and is true in all circumstances.

---

With that being said, the $\mathbf E$ which appears in $\oint \mathbf E \cdot d\mathbf a$ is not always a simple thing to calculate.  For example, if you apply an external electric field $\mathbf E_{ext}$ to a block of material (say, by placing it in between two oppositely-charged plates), then the electric field within the block will be
$$\mathbf E = \mathbf E_{ext} + \mathbf E'$$

where $\mathbf E'$ is the electric field generated by the response of the material to $\mathbf E_{ext}$.  As a simple example, the external field could cause the electrons and atomic nuclei to deform, inducing a secondary field which modifies the external one.

If you *only* know the externally applied field $\mathbf E_{ext}$, then you will need to know the properties of the material in order to calculate $\mathbf E'$ (and by extension, $\oint \mathbf E \cdot d\mathbf a$).  It is in this sense that the material properties may be relevant.

Usually when working with electromagnetic fields in matter, we [modify Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Macroscopic_formulation) to account for the response of the medium to any external fields.  It is worth remembering, though, that the "microscopic" Maxwell equations are always satisfied by the full $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ fields.

Comment: Thanks very much!